# How to create custom UserClaims table in MySQL using ASP.NET Core with EF and Identity?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement ASP.NET Core Identity in my MySQL database. I want to save claims in table named different that *"aspnetuserclaims"*. I managed to point custom tables for users using this in my **OnModelCreating()** method in MyContext which inherits from *IdentityDbContext* class:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
```

But, when I want to do the same with my class which inherits form **IdentityUserClaim** using:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>().ToTable("userclaims").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
```

It doesn't work at all.

Both *ApplicationUser* and *ApplicationUserClaim* are clean class looking like this:

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string> {}
```

Exception:

> MySqlException: Table 'dbname.aspnetuserclaims' doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdentityUser` has generic type overloads. You're using `IdentityUser<TKey>`, but if you want to customize something like the claim class, you need to specify `IdentityUser<TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin>`.

Additionally, `IdentityDbContext` also has generic type overloads, so likewise, you need to ensure you're using the correct overload there, namely: `IdentityDbContext<TUser,TRole,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TRoleClaim,TUserToken>`.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to set Identity to save Claims in table with different name, but same fields as "aspnetuserclaims"?

Comment: Not when you're using a custom `IdentityUserClaim` derivation. For what it's worth, though, you don't necessarily need to derive from each Identity class to use the more expansive generic type overloads. It's perfectly okay to substitute in the base Identity classes as the types. For example: `IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserClaim, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserLogin>`. There, you're only deriving from `IdentityUserClaim`, and the rest of the type params are using the base classes.

Comment: Okay, I think i got this. Kind of. I can overload `IdentityDbContext`, but `IdentityUser` can only be overloaded with `TKey` or nothing (default string).

Comment: Apparently in ASP.NET Core 2.x `IdentityUser<TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin>` this was removed.

Comment: Ah. I just looked it up in the docs and didn't pay attention to versioning. That's probably the least important part anyways. It would only matter for something like a navigation property anyways. The IdentityDbContext should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me understand